# posts_nav_link pulling in multiple post types

Tags: php, wp-query, query-posts, navigation

I have an `archive-regularproducts.php` set up that looks like so:
PHP:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    //content goes here
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <?php query_posts( 'post_type=wpsc-product'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        //content goes here
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <nav id="page_nav">
        <?php posts_nav_link( ' ', ' ', ' '); ?>
    </nav>
```

As you can see I'm also querying the `wpsc-product` post type on this archive page too, the posts display fine, but as I'm using infinite scroll, when it gets to the bottom and pulls in the next page of posts, it's pulling in duplicate `wpsc-product` posts, thus I was wondering if there was a way to either have the `posts_nav_link` function for only the `regularproducts` post type, or a generally better way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `query_posts` should not be used. Here is an [explanation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/31545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) should be avoided at all costs. This is not just my emphasis, but the codex's as well

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

You should also have a look at [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts/1755#1755) for further explanation

You should use `WP_Query` in this instance.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
//content goes here
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=wpsc-product'); ?>
    <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    //content goes here
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<nav id="page_nav">
    <?php posts_nav_link( ' ', ' ', ' '); ?>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatic pagination is only applied to the main query by default. Thus, the pagination is already working as it should. The problem probably lies in the way you're using InfiniteScroll.

IS allows you to target the container and items by a selector you specify. I would suggest wrapping the main query in a div and targeting that with Infinite Scroll. Are you using a plugin or implementing IS manually?

```
<div id="main">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        //content goes here
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php query_posts( 'post_type=wpsc-product'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    //content goes here
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<nav id="page_nav">
    <?php posts_nav_link( ' ', ' ', ' '); ?>
</nav>
```

Then, you should target the container `#main` and all post items inside it.

Comment: `query_posts` should not be used. Here is an [explanation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/31545)

Comment: I'm very aware of that, but that's not within the scope of this question as it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Even though this is not in the scope of the question, you should mention this to the OP and amend your code accordingly. Remember, if someone finds your answer via google, they will use your solution, not knowing that it is wrong. The intention of an answer is not just about a solution to a specific aspect, and ignoring other wrongs that is not in scope

Comment: I disagree. When answering general questions applicable to multiple or general problems, it is quite important to not only help the OP but also ensure that if the original code is adjusted, it is also adjusted to adhere to the coding standards and, in general, be considered "good code". In this case, however, the problem is most likely limited to just the OP's case, and focusing on side issues like this will only serve to make answers less understandable. In this case, helping the OP is more important than providing insight in the proper usage of WordPress.

Comment: What tickles me, if you know the OP is using a function that should not be used, or a function that is depreciated, or code that have a syntax error, you would not correct him, because it is out of scope of his original question?

Comment: Let me first differentiate between these cases. In case of a syntax error, it would in just about all cases be part of the problem, as it will stop code execution :-). If a function is used that's deprecated shouldn't be used, I would let that depend on specific scenario. In this case, I considered correcting it, but I decided against it as I figured it would only add confusion for the OP. However, with this list of comments, it should become clear to the OP that using `query_posts` is a problem nonetheless ;-).